# How to setup Hybrid Connection's secondary connection-string in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, biztalk

I have successfully setup a **Hybrid Connection** to connect my Azure web-application to an on-premises SQL-server. I added the **primary on-premises gateway connection string** and it's listed with the command: `Get-HybridConnection`.

[image]

However it does not always stay connected. Now I wonder what to to with the **secondary** connection string. If I try to add it with `Add-HybridConnection` I get this error:

> Add-HybridConnection : Existing configuration
>   Endpoint=hc://xxxx.hybrid.biztalk.windows.net/xxxxx;SharedAccessKeyName=defaultListener;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxx
>   found.

So you cannot add both the primary and secondary connection strings to the same on-premises **Hybrid Connection Manager**. Should I install another Hybrid Connection Manager on another server and set that up with the secondary connection? I have tried that and it seams to work (connection keeps connected when I stop one of the services), but I can nowhere find info on it.

I also wonder when to click the **Sync Primary Key** or **Sync Secondary Key** in the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one connection string can be synced at a time. [e](from an individual app or hcm)[/e]

When you click 'Sync [Primary/Seconary] Key', this instructs the stack to use the secondary key.

You would use this if you need to regenerate one of the keys, but maintain HC uptime while you do.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unable to test this right now, but I'll accept the answer because it sounds logical and it's the only answer (yet).